# Script to list users and all the groups they are members of

Tags: powershell, csv, foreach, active-directory

I have started a script which compares a username in AD with a specific job title from a CSV, and then lists all the groups (and groups within groups) the user is a member of.

I have checked the function under the first comment and that works as expected, listing all the groups for a user.

next part of the script isnt working as expected, when I try and use the output of the list of users as a variable for my function, I only get a list of groups all the users are members of and not the group and users.

Now I get the following outcome:

```
Group1
Group2
Group3
Group2
Group3
Group4
```

My ideal out put would be something along the lines of:

```
User  MemberOf
----  --------
Bob   Group1, Group2, Group3....
Jim   Group2, Group3, Group4....
```

Code:

```
#Function to recursively check account for group membership
function Get-SubGroups ($account)
{
    $ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"

    $groups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $account
    $allGroups =$null

    while ($groups)
    {
        $allGroups += $groups.Name
        $groups = $groups.Name | Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership   
    }
    $allGroups
}

#CSV with list of job titles and command to get the first user with a job title
$titles = Get-Content 'B:\JobTitles.csv'

#Command to get the list of groups for each user
$users = foreach ($title in $titles)
{
    Get-ADUser -Filter 'Title -Like $title' -Properties Name, SamAccountName, MemberOf, Title | select -First 1
}

foreach ($user in $users)
{
    Get-SubGroups $user | Write-Output
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

do you mean something like that:

```
#Function to recursively check account for group membership
function Get-SubGroups ($account)
    {
    $ErrorActionPreference = "SilentlyContinue"

        $groups = Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $account
        $allGroups =$null

        While($groups)
    {
        $allGroups += $groups.Name
        $groups = $groups.Name | Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership   
    }
        $allGroups
    }

#CSV with list of job titles and command to get the first user with a job title
$titles = Get-Content 'B:\JobTitles.csv'

$users = @()

foreach ($title in $titles)
{
    $users += Get-ADUser -Filter 'Title -Like $title' -Properties Name, SamAccountName, MemberOf, Title | select -First 1
} 

$users | Format-Table -Wrap @{Expression={$_.Name};Label="User";width=25},
@{Expression={[string[]](Get-SubGroups $_) -join ' '};Label="MemberOf"} | Write-Output
```

the output will be:

```
User                      MemberOf                                                                                                                         
----                      --------                                                                                                                         
SomeUser                  Group1 Group2 Group3
SomeUser2                 Group2 Group3
```

Comment: I've tested and that works for my environment, thanks